# Mist error: "unable to connect to socket:timeout"

Tags: mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp

[image: Image contains the error i am getting of couldn't compile source code]

In mist wallet i am getting an error of unable to connect to socket and couldn't compile source code.Do help me where i am doing the mistake.

Comment: Same problem for me.

Comment: Try running mist from a terminal with `--verbosity 4`.  That way you will get more debug information output to the terminal.  Update your question when you have that information.

Answer (score 0):

This error possibly arises due to network connectivity issues or antivirus, proxy , firewall is blocking.Check your settings;
post here if not solved: https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/2801